# Activate event handler only once in javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

`element.addEventListener('dblclick', function () {});`

I believe there is a 'once' option but don't know where to put it?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The `once` option is specified in the optional `options` object parameter that can be passed in like so:

```
element.addEventListener('dblclick', function () {
    ...
}, { once: true });
```

**Documentation:** [EventTarget.addEventListener#Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#syntax)

Comment: Thank you..I forgot once was boolean!

Answer (score -1):

Since `once` has limited support in some browsers I use this method, which is a nice pattern in javascript anyway.

```js
function addEventListenerOnce(elem, name, callback) {
  var foo = function(ev) {
    elem.removeEventListener(name, foo);
    callback.call(elem, ev)
  }
  elem.addEventListener(name, foo)
}

var elem = document.querySelector("button");
addEventListenerOnce(elem, 'click', () => console.log("click"))
```

```html
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very valuable to me and much appreciated!